# Installing Knative without internet

Tags: knative, knative-serving, knative-eventing

Is it possible to install Knative without internet?
Understand that it required K8 to pull images from internet during installation.
Can I download all the necessary images to a private repository and apply yaml to do installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can pre-pull all images used in the Knative core, then the answer is **yes**: you can install and run Knative offline.

It's quite a few images, but you should be able to find all of them easily by inspecting the installation manifests from the [YAML-based installation](https://knative.dev/docs/install/) section of the Knative documentation.

Here are a few examples of images that compose the Knative core (as of Knative v0.22):

Serving

- Serving [controller](https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/v0.22.0/config/core/deployments/controller.yaml#L50)
- Serving [webhook](https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/v0.22.0/config/core/deployments/webhook.yaml#L52)
- Serving [activator](https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/v0.22.0/config/core/deployments/activator.yaml#L41)
- Serving [autoscaler](https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/v0.22.0/config/core/deployments/autoscaler.yaml#L51)
- Serving [queue sidecar](https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/v0.22.0/config/core/configmaps/deployment.yaml#L27)
- Ingress installation. For example, [Kourier](https://github.com/knative-sandbox/net-kourier) needs:

  - Envoy [proxy](https://github.com/knative-sandbox/net-kourier/blob/v0.22.0/config/300-gateway.yaml#L39)
  - Kourier [controller](https://github.com/knative-sandbox/net-kourier/blob/v0.22.0/config/300-controller.yaml#L34)

Eventing

- Eventing [controller](https://github.com/knative/eventing/blob/v0.22.1/config/core/deployments/controller.yaml#L49)
- Eventing [webhook](https://github.com/knative/eventing/blob/v0.22.1/config/core/deployments/controller.yaml#L49)
- Eventing [broker controller](https://github.com/knative/eventing/blob/v0.22.1/config/brokers/mt-channel-broker/deployments/controller.yaml#L48)
- Eventing [broker ingress](https://github.com/knative/eventing/blob/v0.22.1/config/brokers/mt-channel-broker/deployments/broker-ingress.yaml#L37)
- Eventing [broker filter](https://github.com/knative/eventing/blob/v0.22.1/config/brokers/mt-channel-broker/deployments/broker-filter.yaml#L37)
- Eventing [in-memory channel controller](https://github.com/knative/eventing/blob/v0.22.1/config/channels/in-memory-channel/deployments/controller.yaml#L36)
- Eventing [in-memory channel dispatcher](https://github.com/knative/eventing/blob/v0.22.1/config/channels/in-memory-channel/deployments/dispatcher.yaml#L44)

Note: although the `image` attributes I referenced above are in the format `ko://...`, the release manifests documented in the [YAML-based installation](https://knative.dev/docs/install/) section of the Knative documentation contain actual image URLs.

Comment: Hi thanks for your feedback, are you able to highlight some examples in the yaml manifest where it points me to image url and to replace it with repository? Thanks alot

Comment: I updated my answer with a few examples. Please note that this list is not exhaustive, so I invite you to consult the actual release manifests to know exactly what is needed in _your_ installation (whether you need both Serving and Eventing, whether you want to use Istio instead of Kourier, whether you would like to install extra channel implementations in Eventing, etc.)

Comment: Hi thanks. Greatly appreciate your time to craft the answer. I understood it better now!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should absolutely be possible. Assuming Knative Serving for now, you'd fetch the release YAML from https://knative.dev/docs/install/install-serving-with-yaml. You'll need 3 YAML files:

1. serving-crds.yaml
2. serving-core.yaml
3. $network-plugin-of-your-choice.yaml

You can find all necessary images in the respective Deployments in those YAMLs. One notable exception is the queue-proxy image, which you'll find in the `config-deployment` ConfigMap.

Make sure to prepull all those images and replace the coordinates in the YAML with the coordinates of your private registry. Also make sure to grant the necessary pull-rights to the service accounts used.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know that. As i am still quite new to k8, having scanning through the serving-crds.yaml, it is kind of confusing. Do you have an example in the yaml code that state the url where the images can be downloaded from?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you’re likely doing government work or something similar if you’re asking this question. You’re asking us to provide actual code on what to do. Here’s the thing. You will have to docker save all the images. You’ll find these by searching each of the kubernetes manifests. Each container image will be prefixed in the yaml with image:. Then you can tar everything up and take it where you need. you are embarking on a very long and annoying task.